# disable import folding for scala templates in IDEA 12.1.6

Tags: java, intellij-idea, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.2

I'm so tired of this!

Intellij IDEA 12.1.6(build 129.1359) with Play 2.0 Support 0.22.302.

IDEA substitutes my imports

```
import views.html.footballCoupon;
import views.html.message;
import views.html.genericCouponTemplate;
import views.html.review;
```

with

```
import views.html.*;
```

and (surprise surprise) immediately breaks the code with errors like:

```
Recerence to 'footballCoupon' is ambiguous, both 'views.html.footballCoupon$' and 'views.html.footballCoupon' match
```

How to disable such folding or to solve this problem in any other way?

Comment: Usually its a Code Style setting ("Class count to use import with '*'), but I see that there's no such setting for Scala language... I suggest submitting a ticket to them.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there used to be such a setting, looked a while for it but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

In Project Settings -> Scala there is an option called "Class count to use '_'" or something like that. Just crank that number up to 99 or so.